# MSBuild - treat Embedded Resources as if they were Content

Tags: .net, msbuild, resources, embedded-resource

We have an MVC solution with certain files (js, cshtml) being "Embedded Resources" to allow the developers to debug them in visual studio. Is there a way to make MSbuild treat them as Content, so that they are published as files instead of embedding them during build?

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, right click the file and click "Properties".
In the properties page under Advanced, select "Copy if newer" in the "Copy to output directory" property.

Comment: This copies the file to the bin directory, next to dlls. This is not what we need..

Comment: @Czenda - perhaps you would like to explain exactly what you do need and how that differs from this answer.

Comment: @phuzi - the idea was that in addition to embedding these files in the output dll, they would also be treated as"Content", since we don't use them as embedded - it's only there for the debugging. We have to copy them anyway, as if they were Content. This answer is no good because it causes those files being copied to /bin, instead of published to their relative path, as if they were Content. This is as good as I can explain it, sorry...

Comment: Hmm, unusual. Used to use IE when debugging Javascript with VS but much prefer to use Chrome as I find the experience nicer. As for your views there really shouldn't be much code to debug as if you're following a normal MVC pattern with all your real code and logic happening in the controller/service layers.